# DigitalOcean Loadbalancer and Cloudflare DNS

Tags: cloudflare, digital-ocean

I have moodle instances on DigitalOcean, that connect to one load balancer instances (DigitalOcean load-balancer).
I'd like to use Cloudflare DNS with a proxy and point it to my load-balancer's IP address. The issue is that the load-balancer can only access one of my two moodle instances (droplets) and not the other. When I untagged (release) my moodle instances, the connection 504 error comes up.

[image: 1]

The DNS itself refers to the subdomain of a school site.

[image: 2]

DNS records

[image: 3]

How can I fix that, or is it a limitation of the free version? I'll pay if it's necessary to resolve the problem.

Comment: Solved, I forgot to put my loadbalancer IP address on the record. Instead, I put droplet Public ip address

Comment: Please: either delete your question, or [answer to it yourself](https://serverfault.com/help/self-answer) and accept it later. Don't rewrite the question as "solved".

Comment: @A.B okay, I'm new though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I forgot to put my load balancer IP address on the record. Instead, I put droplet Public IP address

Comment: and in 24h please don't forget to accept your own answer, else we will reminded until the end of the universe to solve this one ;)

Comment: Okay I will do it 6 hours from now